# Parametererised project in Jenkins: parameter is not passed

Tags: jenkins, parameter-passing, cloud-foundry

I want to use parameter in one field in Jenkins like this:

```
location/${appname}
```

It seems like it's not working because Jenkins is taking it as a whole string and not taking "${appname}" as a dynamic variable.

Cloud Foundry plugin version: 2.3.1

Jenkins version: 2.138.2

Log:

```
Cloud Foundry Plugin: INFO: Looks like we are on a distributed system... Transferring build artifacts from the slave to the master. INFO: Transferring from ***/***/location/${appname} to /***/***/ java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unzipped output directory was empty. at com.hpe.cloudfoundryjenkins.CloudFoundryPushTask.transferArtifactsToMaster(CloudFoundryPushTask.java:234)..
```

Comment: Could you please provide full command with this parameter? How you're passing `appname` parameter to your job? Did you tried to use `"location/${params.appname}"` ?

Comment: The string parameter is called "appname" and, in one of the fields for post-build action called "Application Path" I am just trying to pass the parameter's value there simply like this: `location/${appname}`. In other fields if I use just `${appname}` it works well, but in this case with `location/` before the parameter, it is not passing the value of appname.

Comment: Do you use freestyle job, or Jenkins pipeline? Anyway, I wrote an answer for both, please check that.

Comment: I am using the "Push to Cloud Foundry" plugin and trying to enter the configuration in Jenkins.

Comment: If both `"location/${env.appname}"` and  `"location/${params.appname}"` is not working, try to move this step from post-build action to build action and check again. Also please provide your log errors.

Comment: It seems that the field "application path" in Cloud Foundry plugin will not accept any dynamic variable (in this case, our parameter). Log:                               
`Cloud Foundry Plugin:
INFO: Looks like we are on a distributed system... Transferring build artifacts from the slave to the master.
INFO: Transferring from ***/***/location/${appname} to /***/***/
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unzipped output directory was empty.
 at com.hpe.cloudfoundryjenkins.CloudFoundryPushTask.transferArtifactsToMaster(CloudFoundryPushTask.java:234)..`

Comment: Can you put a real path instead of `${appname}` parameter and re-run the job to see if all will be running correctly? Also please provide versions of Jenkins and Cloud Foundry plugin.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187186/discussion-between-bese-and-biruk1230).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use single quotes.

Like `location/'${appname}'`.

Comment: In my case this line works fine: `if ("${release_mode}".equalsIgnoreCase('preprod_stable'))`

Comment: This is not working as well. I tried with single quotes ' ' and double quotes " " but none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try `"location/${env.appname}"` syntax for freestyle job.

If it's not working, you can try to use [Jenkins pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/) with `"location/${params.appname}"` syntax, see "Inline manifest with service creation and binding" example from [Cloud Foundry](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Cloud+Foundry+Plugin) plugin.